# Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\Shop\config\bootstrap.php on line 5

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой

```
 <?php
 // create.php

 require_once "../config/bootstrap.php";
 global $entityManager;
 $sql = new Users();
 $email = 'sd';
 $password = 123;

 $sql->setEmail($email);
 $sql->setPassword($password);


 $entityManager->persist($sql);       
 $entityManager->flush();
```

Скрин файлов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну и зачем тогда `../config`? `./bootstrap.php` хватит

Comment: `bootstrap.php`, по идее, находится в подпапке `autoload`, верно? В Вашем случае получается, что программа пытается в папке `config` сразу найти там, без перехода в подпапки и пр. `bootstrap.php`

Comment: "Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой" --- а что тут помогать?  нужно корректный путь написать. Разберитесь как они пишутся корректно и всё

Comment: './bootstrap' и 'bootstrap' - пробовал не работает

Comment: А причём тут bootstrap файл? Он то как раз найден и загружается.  Укажите правильный путь до *vendor/autoload.php*  в файле bootstrap.php. Ну или загрузите зависимости через composer, если такой каталог отсутствует где-либо в проекте